# How to iterate through an object that is pointing to array of doubles?

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

I have an object that is pointing to an array of doubles.
How can I iterate through the array to extract doubles?

```
object data = new object()
func(ref data);
```

if you look at data in watch window it shows...

```
data {double[123]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast object to array of doubles:

```
double[] array = (double[])data;
```

And then you can access items or iterate over array:

```
foreach(double value in array)
   //...
```

Comment: lol, so simple... thanks.  didn't know you can cast an array like that.  still have a lot to learn.

Comment: hmmm.  did I do that?  if I did, I didn't mean to.  Since I'm new here I am very limited on what I can do.  I up voted and it makes me wait. I tried to up vote again it says it requires 15 reputations.  So I may have down voted by accident due to frustration and I didn't mean to.

Answer (score 0):

if you *know* its an array of doubles you can cast to to that type:

```
double[] values = (double[])data;
```

This will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the type of `data` is not an array of doubles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator

```
double[] array = data as double[];
if(array != null)
{
   ..
}
```

It avoids the `InvalidCastException`, if type of `data` is not `double[]`  your array become `null`.

Answer (score -1):

If you expect callers for your method to always be passing in some type of data that can be iterated, and the method needs to iterate it, then it shouldn't accept a parameter of type`object`, it should accept a parameter of type `IEnumerable`, or possibly `IEnumerable<T>` with some specific type (such as `double`).

You should *no* just accept an `object` and try to cast it.  Doing that is not properly indicating to the callers of the method that they need to pass in something that can be iterated.

Also note that you probably don't need to pass the object by reference (using the `ref` keyword).  That is only useful for changing what object is referenced.  Generally that's not appropriate.  If a new object is generated by this method you probably want to return it, rather than mutating the parameter.